# Restart process with execl

Tags: python-3.x

Im running a python program in a git repo, every night im planing to do a pull on master branch and update the repo if nececery.
If the code has changed in the repo (new commit hash) I will restart my program.

I have a small test script to verify that the restart works but I cannot get it to work as my test prints after the restart does not show up.

```py
def start_new(new):
    python = sys.executable
    print(python)
    if new == 1:
        #git.py is the file we are in already
        os.execl(python, python, 'git.py', 'test')

start_new(len(sys.argv))
print(2)
```

According to documentation execl will imidiatly replace the old process with the new process and not return.
What I expect in console output is:

```
path to python
path to python
2
```

But the only thing I get is path to python

What am I missing?

EDIT: Problem Existed in development environment which failed to print after restart.

Comment: "The old process" is the process that calls ''execl''. So "print" is called exactly once, at most. - BTW perhaps it's better to print os.getpid() value, which is (almost) unique.

Comment: My thought would be that the call stack would be something like.
First it gets invoked from cmd line calling start_new for the first time
so that would result in the first print of path to python. then as the sys.argv is 1 it will run os.execl on it self, resulting in that it will run start_new but with an sys.argv of 2 so it will not create a new version this time and thus print 2 at the end